# CharJs Using Razor

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

My web app is about an Online Poll that manages Question's and answers, I can also vote on answers, so now I only need to show on a graphic the number of votes for each answer, I saw this **Chart.js** api so i'm trying to implement it to my app but having issues on Converting the Json objects the right way.

```
<html>
<head>
<script 
 src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.2/Chart.js"> 
</script>
     </head>
   <body>
   <div id="chart_container">
       <canvas id="myChart" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
        <script>
              var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext('2d');
                var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
                    type: 'bar', data: {
                        labels: @Html.Raw(ViewBag.DataPoints)

                            datasets: [{
                                label: 'Numero de respostas',
                                data: @Html.Raw(ViewBag.DataPoints)

                                borderWidth: 1,
                            }]
                    },
                options: {scales: {yAxes: [{ticks: {beginAtZero: true}}]}}});
    </script>
</div>
```

Here is my controller code:

```
 List<DataPoint> dataPoints = new List<DataPoint>();
            foreach (var resposta in poolDbContext.Answers)
            {
                dataPoints.Add(new DataPoint(resposta.Text, answer.Votes.Count()));
            }
            ViewBag.DataPoints = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dataPoints);

            ViewBag.Data = question.Answers;
            ViewBag.ObjectName = question.Text;
```

And here is my DataPoint Model:

```
  [DataContract]
public class DataPoint
{
    public DataPoint(string labels, double data)
    {
        this.Label = labels;
        this.Y = data;
    }

    //Explicitly setting the name to be used while serializing to JSON.
    [DataMember(Name = "labels")]
    public string Label = "";

    //Explicitly setting the name to be used while serializing to JSON.
    [DataMember(Name = "data")]
    public Nullable<double> Y = null;
}
```

> **I have managed to make it display the right number of bars but they don't have a value or an answer Text**

[EmptyBars Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1f1Y7.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work and also you can't do a `foreach` loop inside a javascript array:

```
 <html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.2/Chart.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="chart_container">
            <canvas id="myChart" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
        </div>

           <script>
            var arrayOfAnswers = JSON.parse('@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.Answers.ToList()))');
            var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext('2d');
            var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
                type: 'bar',
                data: {
                    labels: arrayOfAnswers,
                    datasets: [{
                        label: '# of Answers',
                        data: [//Enter data for all answers labels, corresponding to bars],
                        borderWidth: 1
                    }]
                },
                options: {
                    scales: {
                        yAxes: [{
                            ticks: {
                                beginAtZero: true
                            }
                        }]
                    }
                }
            });
            </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```